# List filenames and a count of the resident pages in filesystem cache?

Tags: linux, file, memory, dictionary

In RHEL is there a way to list filenames and a count of the resident pages in filesystem cache?

Comment: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/caching/fscache.txt